# Unable to pass object in createAsyncThunk in Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to pass two parameters in createProductReview action when submitHandler function runs.
One is **id** and other one is an **object** containing two items. The problem is that I am unable to pass the object in createProductReview action. It gives undefine when I console log it in reducer function. I want to know how can I pass these two arguments without getting error.
Please check out attached image for error

**submitHandler** **function**

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(createProductReview({ id, { rating, comment } }));
  };
```

**createProductReview**

```
export const createProductReview = createAsyncThunk(
  'reviewProduct',
  async ({ productId, review }, thunkAPI) => {
    console.log(productId, review);
    try {
      const {
        userLogin: { userInfo },
      } = thunkAPI.getState();
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
        },
      };
      await axios.post(`/api/products/${productId}/reviews`, review, config);
    } catch (error) {
      const newError =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(newError);
    }
  }
);
```

[image: submitHandler error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, you need to pass keys to the object so it should be like this

```
dispatch(createProductReview({ productId:id, review:{ rating, comment } }));
```

Specially, when you are destructuring it in the function. Since destructure works by getting the object with its key.

so for example:

```
const x = {temp:"1"}
const {temp} = x;
console.log(temp);
//1
```